# CSS Fixed Position on the right of the main centered content

Tags: html, css

I've got a site with main content area of 960px with `margin:0 auto;`  I need to fix  position some social icons to the right of the main content area (like `left:100%` so it sits outside the main content area but is attached to right side).

I can't use absolute because they want the buttons visible in same location all the time as page scrolls.  I can't use `right:0` as that would put it on the right of the browser window, not right of that main content area.  what's the best way to fix something based off your main content area?  I can adjust markup if needed.

EDIT:
this is what I have now for markup basically.

```
<div class="mainContentArea">
    <div class="socialIconsWrapper">
        <div class="socialIcons">
```

Comment: Please add your html and your css

Comment: Use `transform: translateX(-100%);` with `left:100%`

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Since I didn't get any response, I deleted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the content area in footer section and then use left:100%;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left: calc(50% + 480px)` to set the position of the fixed social icons. Example given below:

```css
.page {
  width: 100%;
}
.main {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.social {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  left: calc(50% + 160px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="social">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex.

```css
.main {
  width: 980px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.social-icons {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="social-icons">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately it's an outdated site and they aren't even using HTML5 lol.  Was hoping for another solution that has full browser support at the moment.

Comment: @Chief What is full browser support? :) https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @RadovanSkendzic flex is not well supported in IE. I've had issues even in IE 11. Chief I don't think it matters if it's an outdated site, but depends on if a lot of traffic will come from IE. If not, using flex is safe and probably future-proof.

Comment: @DimSum I agree it's not well supported, but there are still workarounds. And for this particular problem, I believe this could be a solution.

Comment: @RadovanSkendzic I'm not sure. He said he wants "it sits outside the main content area but is attached to right side", so the images should sit outside the red box, but right next to the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `jquery` to calculate right value outside of the main content area. I put `$(window).resize()` function so that every resize of the screen the value of the right of the social icons wrapper remains.

*Below are the steps on how I come up with the value of the right of social icons with fixed in position:*

-get the `window width`

-substract `window width` to `main content width`

-the value from substraction divide by 2

-after that substract to `social icons wrapper width`

-then finally, you get the value of the social icons wrapper right from main content area

Here's my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/bc7thcLn/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $contrgt = $(window).width() - $('.mainContentArea').width();
  $socwd = $('.socialIconsWrapper').width();

  $('.socialIconsWrapper').css('right', ($contrgt/2)-$socwd+'px');

    $(window).resize(function(){ 
     $contrgt = $(window).width() - $('.mainContentArea').width();
     $socwd = $('.socialIconsWrapper').width();
     $('.socialIconsWrapper').css('right', ($contrgt/2)-$socwd+'px');
    });
    
    console.log('right='+$contrgt+'px');   
});
```

```css
*{ border-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; } /* used for global styling */

.mainContentArea{ max-width: 400px; margin: 20px auto; width: 100%; background: blue; color: #fff; }
.socialIconsWrapper{ background: red; position: fixed; z-index: 99; }
.socialIconsWrapper a{ color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <div class="mainContentArea">
    <div class="socialIconsWrapper">
        <div class="socialIcons">
           <a href="">fb</a>
           <a href="">twitter</a>
           <a href="">youtube</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
    some content here some content here some content here
</div>
```